# Python : Reading CSV using np.genfromtxt resulting in different number of columns

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I am using np.genfromtxt to read a csv. I am not sure why it is raising a ValueError(errmsg) on the data. When I read the file in excel and it shows a total of 23 columns for all the 33 rows in the file

Here is the code and error:

csv = np.genfromtxt (fname, delimiter=",",names=True)

Here is a snippet of the csv records:

```
,mean_fit_time,mean_score_time,mean_test_score,mean_train_score,param_NN__alpha,param_NN__hidden_layer_sizes,params,rank_test_score,split0_test_score,split0_train_score,split1_test_score,split1_train_score,split2_test_score,split2_train_score,split3_test_score,split3_train_score,split4_test_score,split4_train_score,std_fit_time,std_score_time,std_test_score,std_train_score
0,0.34166226387023924,0.0010362625122070312,0.842927342927343,0.8468980402379758,0.1,"(7,)","{'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (7,)}",25,0.8420706295240185,0.8475292052871167,0.8398771660451854,0.8463774474853288,0.845360824742268,0.846158065046893,0.8385256691531373,0.8486892618185806,0.8488040377441299,0.8457362215519605,0.05093153997183547,0.00018195987247183776,0.0037378988316037944,0.0010747322296072162
1,0.5543142318725586,0.0018250465393066407,0.8465250965250966,0.8527554135893668,0.1,"(25, 7)","{'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (25, 7)}",5,0.846018863785918,0.8530137662480118,0.846018863785918,0.8589919376953875,0.8479929809168677,0.8496681840618658,0.8400614304519526,0.851486234506965,0.8525345622119815,0.8506169454346038,0.10835399357094619,0.00018853748087819175,0.004013613789285713,0.003306836154659678
2,0.5266880512237548,0.0013680458068847656,0.8437609687609687,0.8478413817137904,0.1,"(11, 7)","{'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (11, 7)}",17,0.842509322219785,0.8479679701639884,0.8354902390875192,0.8431964021280096,0.8455801710901514,0.8520265452750507,0.8433523475208424,0.851595919710431,0.8518762343647136,0.8444200712914725,0.1041624682160838,0.0003233587082439388,0.005278162504355272,0.0036030369022985215
3,0.49459095001220704,0.0011162281036376954,0.8406458406458407,0.845428443186931,0.1,"(7, 5)","{'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (7, 5)}",32,0.8383417416100022,0.848461580650469,0.8429480149155516,0.8501617945483464,0.8468962491774512,0.8514780891789612,0.8312856516015796,0.8381046396841066,0.8437568575817423,0.8389361118727722,0.10397613499936685,0.00018889068500539376,0.005421511394261151,0.005726975087304059
4,0.6175418376922608,0.0024899959564208983,0.8449017199017199,0.8508140227747922,0.1,"(25, 11, 7)","{'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (25, 11, 7)}",11,0.8414125904803685,0.8493939560138211,0.8427286685676684,0.8546591345362804,0.8501864443957008,0.8519716996654417,0.8459850811759544,0.8564769112646704,0.8441957428132544,0.8415684123937482,0.1940231074769015,0.00047604030307216253,0.003049662553913791,0.005209439647677219
```

Error Received:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #3 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #4 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #5 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #6 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #7 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #8 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #9 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #10 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #11 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #12 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #13 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #14 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #15 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #16 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #17 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #18 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #19 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #20 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #21 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #22 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #23 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #24 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #25 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #26 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #27 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #28 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #29 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #30 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #31 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
    Line #32 (got 28 columns instead of 22)
    Line #33 (got 26 columns instead of 22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `,` as a delimiter while a lot of your column values contain elements themselves. You'd need to specify an explicit quotechar to get this to work.

Fortunately, `pandas` handles this really well without much handholding. You could try loading your data with `read_csv` and then convert the loaded dataframe to an array.

```
import pandas as pd
array = pd.read_csv(name, index_col=[0]).values
```

---

The loaded dataframe (what you get before calling `.values`) looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(name, index_col=[0])
print(df)

   mean_fit_time  mean_score_time  mean_test_score  mean_train_score  \
0       0.341662         0.001036         0.842927          0.846898   
1       0.554314         0.001825         0.846525          0.852755   
2       0.526688         0.001368         0.843761          0.847841   
3       0.494591         0.001116         0.840646          0.845428   
4       0.617542         0.002490         0.844902          0.850814   

   param_NN__alpha param_NN__hidden_layer_sizes  \
0              0.1                         (7,)   
1              0.1                      (25, 7)   
2              0.1                      (11, 7)   
3              0.1                       (7, 5)   
4              0.1                  (25, 11, 7)   

                                              params  rank_test_score  \
0  {'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (...               25   
1  {'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (...                5   
2  {'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (...               17   
3  {'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (...               32   
4  {'NN__alpha': 0.1, 'NN__hidden_layer_sizes': (...               11   

   split0_test_score  split0_train_score       ...         split2_test_score  \
0           0.842071            0.847529       ...                  0.845361   
1           0.846019            0.853014       ...                  0.847993   
2           0.842509            0.847968       ...                  0.845580   
3           0.838342            0.848462       ...                  0.846896   
4           0.841413            0.849394       ...                  0.850186   

   split2_train_score  split3_test_score  split3_train_score  \
0            0.846158           0.838526            0.848689   
1            0.849668           0.840061            0.851486   
2            0.852027           0.843352            0.851596   
3            0.851478           0.831286            0.838105   
4            0.851972           0.845985            0.856477   

   split4_test_score  split4_train_score  std_fit_time  std_score_time  \
0           0.848804            0.845736      0.050932        0.000182   
1           0.852535            0.850617      0.108354        0.000189   
2           0.851876            0.844420      0.104162        0.000323   
3           0.843757            0.838936      0.103976        0.000189   
4           0.844196            0.841568      0.194023        0.000476   

   std_test_score  std_train_score  
0        0.003738         0.001075  
1        0.004014         0.003307  
2        0.005278         0.003603  
3        0.005422         0.005727  
4        0.003050         0.005209  

[5 rows x 22 columns
```

And yes, columns are automatically converted to the appropriate datatypes.

```
print(df.dtypes)

mean_fit_time                   float64
mean_score_time                 float64
mean_test_score                 float64
mean_train_score                float64
param_NN__alpha                 float64
param_NN__hidden_layer_sizes     object
params                           object
rank_test_score                   int64
split0_test_score               float64
split0_train_score              float64
split1_test_score               float64
split1_train_score              float64
split2_test_score               float64
split2_train_score              float64
split3_test_score               float64
split3_train_score              float64
split4_test_score               float64
split4_train_score              float64
std_fit_time                    float64
std_score_time                  float64
std_test_score                  float64
std_train_score                 float64
dtype: object
```

*Statutory warning*: This data, owing to its nature, will probably be more useful to you as a python list, than a numpy array (which is optimised to work with scalars).

Comment: i did not have any missing values since the dataframe was output of a result of a gridsearch..

Comment: @EB Notice that your delimiter is a comma, but a lot of your cell values contain commas too ;-) Which, by the way, pandas handles nicely.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, i understand that , but can i not specify that the other fields are enclosed with quotes if that is not possible, .. I was planning to read the file and add double quotes on all the fields to make it consistent, and then pass it to genfromtxt but I was not able to find a way to pass that to genfromtxt that my columns are enclosed with double quotes.. if it is even possible

Comment: @EB No, you need `np.genfromtxt` to handle `quotechar` functionality, which I don't believe it is capable of. What is the problem with importing pandas and using it?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, yes the pandas implementation works as well.. just was wondering why the weird behavior of genfromtxt

Comment: @EB Unfortunately, no getting around it. Genfromtxt is not meant to work with weird objects, as your CSV has, it just doesn't have the quotechar functionality that pandas has (see edit). If it helps, to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thanks for the advice.. just wondering how did you get the display come out with the headings.. with just loading it thru pd.read.csv...